Are some badges too hard?
Several gold badges have never been earned. Have any of them even nearly been earned? Like, this one? Has anyone come close? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/27/legendary
If it's too hard, is there any interest in modifying the requirements?

They've all been earned on other sites

@DoubleAA ah, was under the impression they were available to be changed per site

Yep, been here for five years and I've only had five days where I've earned 200 rep. in one day. Those are the days where you discover that there's a 200 points daily limit (exempting bounties). On the other hand, I haven't gotten the Peer Pressure badge yet.

@Harel13 you are a legend so it's a shame you don't have it imo. 5 sounds right for this site. I haven't earned 200 points in a day even once, after 2 years of sincere contributions. It's a sign of my contributions no doubt, but i still find it hard to imagine anyone ever doing it 150 times!

@RabbiKaii I'm sure you'll manage it eventually. I think I only managed it when I was still in yeshiva and had more spare time during the day for this sort of stuff. I agree that doing it 150 times is mind-boggling.
